# MySQL SELECT IF MAX: unexpected behaviour

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, sql-null

I have a MySQL table with no records in it.

```
-- all of these return false
SELECT IF(MAX(id), 'true', 'false') FROM `vcr_grades`
SELECT IF(MAX(id) = NULL, 'true', 'false') FROM `vcr_grades`
SELECT IF(!MAX(id), 'true', 'false') FROM `vcr_grades`

-- returns NULL
SELECT MAX(id) FROM `vcr_grades`
```

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is set to another value than `1`. Primary key is `id`.

What am I missing??

Comment: Yes, I did it before. Why does `SELECT IF(MAX(id) = NULL, 'true', 'false') FROM 'vcr_grades'` returns false even though I have no records?

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` always increases so you dont have collisions with `id`s. If you deleted then reused a previous `id` you could have incorrect mappings with other tables. Not sure that answers your question though. What are you asking here?

Comment: The test for null is IS NULL not = null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apparently have zero rows.

When you use an aggregate function like MAX() or COUNT(), the query will return at least one row, even if the table has zero rows.

`MAX(id)` returns NULL if there are no non-NULL id values in the set of rows it scans. If you have zero rows, this will return NULL.

`NULL = NULL` does not return true, it returns NULL.

```
mysql> select null=null;
+-----------+
| null=null |
+-----------+
|      NULL |
+-----------+
```

`IF(NULL, 'true', 'false')` returns 'false'.

You might like to read about the [null-safe equal operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

```
mysql> select null <=> null;
+---------------+
| null <=> null |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
```

Comment: I must read about MySQL operators, I had no idea about it. Thank you for clarifying :)

Answer (score 1):

In all of these cases `MAX(id)` returns `NULL`, also `!MAX(id)` is `!NULL` which again is `NULL`.
A Boolean expression which is `NULL` is **not** `TRUE` so in all first 3 queries the result is the `FALSE` part of the function `IF()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your table seems to be empty:

- `MAX(id)` returns `NULL`; `id` is the primary key of the table so it cannot be `NULL`, so this results indicates that there are no records at all in the table
- `IF(MAX(id), 'true', 'false')` yields false because `NULL` is logically false
- `IF(MAX(id) = NULL, 'true', 'false')` is false because `NULL` is not equal to `NULL` (to check for `NULL`ness, you need `IS NULL`)
- `IF(!MAX(id), 'true', 'false')` is false because `! NULL` is logically false

You can try the following expression instead, which should yield `'true'`

```
IF(MAX(id) IS NULL, 'true', 'false')
```

Answer (score 1):

Some misconceptions I spot:

- `NULL` is neither equal nor different to anything else... including itself:

  ```
  mysql> SELECT 1 = 1, 1 <> 1, 1 = NULL, 1 <> NULL, NULL = NULL, NULL <> NULL;
  +-------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
  | 1 = 1 | 1 <> 1 | 1 = NULL | 1 <> NULL | NULL = NULL | NULL <> NULL |
  +-------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
  |     1 |      0 |     NULL |      NULL |        NULL |         NULL |
  +-------+--------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  ```

  That's why we have the `IS` operator, as in:

  ```
  mysql> SELECT 1 IS NULL, 1 IS NOT NULL, NULL IS NULL, NULL IS NOT NULL;
  +-----------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
  | 1 IS NULL | 1 IS NOT NULL | NULL IS NULL | NULL IS NOT NULL |
  +-----------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
  |         0 |             1 |            1 |                0 |
  +-----------+---------------+--------------+------------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  ```
- The `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature is nothing but a global counter you can use to generate unique non-reusable table-wide integers. The fact that it's typically used to populate primary keys doesn't make it a synonym for primary key.
- `MAX(id)` does exactly what the name suggests and nothing else: grab the maximum value in column `id`. If the table is empty it will not go and grab current AUTO_INCREMENT value from table definition, it will just return `NULL` [as documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max):

  > If there are no matching rows, `MAX()` returns `NULL`.
- [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) does not really play any role here but:

  > If `expr1` is `TRUE` (`expr1 <> 0` and `expr1 <> NULL`), `IF()` returns `expr2`. Otherwise, it returns `expr3`.

  (This description is actually misleading because `expr1 <> NULL` actually means what plain English suggests.)